# How can I see backups for corporate accounts in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, backup

I have a personal and a corporate Google account, the corporate being in the domain of my company. When I head to my personal account, I see a tab "backups" in the left side of the page as shown in the below image 
[image]

from there I can manage the backups made in that account. However, in my corporate account I can't see the backups tab even though I'm perfectly able to backup my data using said account, as shown below

[image]

I'm aware that clicking the gear -> "configuration" -> "manage apps" will show me all the apps, but I want to show the "backups" tab of possible.

**Is there any way of showing the "backups" tab in a Google Drive corporate account?**

Comment: are you an administrator of the corporate account?

Comment: No I'm not. I'm just a regular user.

Comment: Which apps have you backed up into your G Suite account?

Comment: I'm asking this in general as I see several backups in my personal account. However, I was looking for Whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know for sure that you've backed up an application to your G Suite account (i.e. logged in to that Google account when in the app you were trying to back up), it's likely you haven't backed any apps up to that account. For one, if you've only got one WhatsApp number, you can't back up to two Google accounts at the same time, so there isn't a reason to expect that your G Suite account has backed up your WhatsApp account. When there aren't any backups, Google Drive automatically hides that tab.

Comment: This is not the case, as I have just performed a backup and the tab is still not showing up

Comment: A backup for which application?

Comment: Whatsapp, for instance. But I have performed backups for other applications, like my phone settings. And I'm sure the backup is performed as I was able to recover it from that account, just that it does not shows up in the tab

Comment: Have you backed up your WhatsApp account to your personal Google account? If so, why did you change the Google account that you're using to back up your WhatsApp account?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being helpful. It would be better if Google representatives used this forum.

Comment: I have two WhatsApp accounts: a business one (backed up in the business Google account) and a personal one (backed up in the personal Google account). I just want to mimic the behaviour of the personal account (i.e see the "backups" tab) onto the corporate one. I'm glad you are trying to help